# FTP Download via VBA 64-Bit

Tags: excel, vba, ftp

I'm trying to download a .zip file from a FTP password protected site via VBA (64 bit). Once I get the hang of it I'll use cell values to dictate the file name, but for now this is what I have. I'm new to FTP so no idea what I'm doing wrong... download fails every time. It doesn't return an error when debugging just prints "fail" as per my code instructions.

I've pulled the code together from a 32 bit source and changed it to be compatible with 64 bit.

Is there anything that needs to be enabled in VBA>Tools>References? Or perhaps on my browser?

```
Private Const FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_UNKNOWN     As Long = 0
Private Const INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD          As Long = &H80000000

Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetOpenA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal sAgent As String, _
    ByVal lAccessType As Long, _
    ByVal sProxyName As String, _
    ByVal sProxyBypass As String, _
    ByVal lFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetConnectA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal hInternetSession As Long, _
    ByVal sServerName As String, _
    ByVal nServerPort As Long, _
    ByVal sUsername As String, _
    ByVal sPassword As String, _
    ByVal lService As Long, _
    ByVal lFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lcontext As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FtpGetFileA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal hConnect As Long, _
    ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, _
    ByVal lpszNewFile As String, _
    ByVal fFailIfExists As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal dwContext As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetCloseHandle Lib "wininet" ( _
    ByVal hInet As Long) As Long
```

-

```
Sub FtpDownload(ByVal strRemoteFile As String, ByVal strLocalFile As String, ByVal strHost As String, ByVal lngPort As Long, ByVal strUser As String, ByVal strPass As String)
    Dim hOpen   As Long
    Dim hConn   As Long

    hOpen = InternetOpenA("FTPGET", 1, vbNullString, vbNullString, 1)
    hConn = InternetConnectA(hOpen, strHost, lngPort, strUser, strPass, 1, 0, 2)

    If FtpGetFileA(hConn, strRemoteFile, strLocalFile, 1, 0, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_UNKNOWN Or INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0) Then
        Debug.Print "Success"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Fail"
    End If

    'Close connections
    InternetCloseHandle hConn
    InternetCloseHandle hOpen
End Sub
```

-

```
Sub TestDownload()
  FtpDownload "filename.zip", "C:\Users\Desktop\Files\filename.zip", _
              "ftp://mysitehere.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/", 21, "myusernamehere", "mypasswordhere"
End Sub
```

Comment: All references are in your code. That's what the `declare` statements do. VBA will `LoadLibrary` and do a `GetProcAddress` based on your `declare` statement. If you read the documentation you see it says you must call `GetLastError` to get the error. In VBA we have to use the inbuilt VBA way as VBA has already called this function automatically so we can't call it again reliably. VBA puts it in `err.LastDllError`.

Comment: @Mark thanks! Any advice as to why the code isn't executing correctly and downloading the file?

Comment: What's the error? `Debug.Print err.lastdllerror`.

Comment: @Mark `Debug.Print err.lastdllerror` returns `6`

Comment: Please edit extra information into your question. Which function returns `6`. 6 Is a Windows error saying your code is wrong. Internet errors are in the 12000+ range. Looking up `6` by typing in a command prompt - `net helpmsg 6` returns _The handle is invalid._. So hOpen or hConn are invalid because one or both of those functions didn't work. So you need to get their `err.lastdllerror`.

Comment: Your code structure for `FtpGetFileA` of testing success needs to be replicated on the earlier two functions.

Comment: Also non passive FTP cannot get through firewalls. You are not specifying passive. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/win32/wininet/api-flags in `InternetConnect` See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetconnecta and for an overview of FTP https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/win32/wininet/ftp-sessions

Comment: @Mark `hOpen` returns `0`, while `hConn` returns `12007`. I'll look into the firewall thingy- looks `12007` is a firewall issue. Thanks!

Comment: **Windows Error 0x2EE7 (12007)** Windows Internet Error: `The server name or address could not be resolved`

Answer (score 0):

For pointer variables use LongPtr instead of Long type.

```
Private Const FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_UNKNOWN     As Long = 0
Private Const INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD          As Long = &H80000000

Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetOpenA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal sAgent As String, _
    ByVal lAccessType As Long, _
    ByVal sProxyName As String, _
    ByVal sProxyBypass As String, _
    ByVal lFlags As Long) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetConnectA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal hInternetSession As LongPtr, _
    ByVal sServerName As String, _
    ByVal nServerPort As Long, _
    ByVal sUsername As String, _
    ByVal sPassword As String, _
    ByVal lService As Long, _
    ByVal lFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lcontext As Long) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FtpGetFileA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal hConnect As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, _
    ByVal lpszNewFile As String, _
    ByVal fFailIfExists As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal dwContext As Long) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetCloseHandle Lib "wininet" ( _
    ByVal hInet As LongPtr) As LongPtr


Sub FtpDownload(ByVal strRemoteFile As String, ByVal strLocalFile As String, ByVal strHost As String, ByVal lngPort As Long, ByVal strUser As String, ByVal strPass As String)
    Dim hOpen   As LongPtr
    Dim hConn   As LongPtr

    hOpen = InternetOpenA("FTPGET", 1, vbNullString, vbNullString, 1)
    hConn = InternetConnectA(hOpen, strHost, lngPort, strUser, strPass, 1, 0, 2)

    If FtpGetFileA(hConn, strRemoteFile, strLocalFile, 1, 0, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_UNKNOWN Or INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0) Then
        Debug.Print "Success"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Fail"
    End If

    'Close connections
    InternetCloseHandle hConn
    InternetCloseHandle hOpen
End Sub
```